# opengl binding of target in thread fails

Tags: opengl

I am trying to update the content of a vertex buffer by a thread.
Inside the thread function it is not possible to bind the buffer
to a target, or retrieve a pointer via glMapBufferRange.
I always get the error 1282. Outside thge thread function everything 
works fine.

```
  while( t_con->out_loop )
  {
    Sleep( t_con->sleep_time );
    if( t_con->in_loop )
    {
      t_con->count++;                                                                // thread counter up  

      EnterCriticalSection( &__cr_sec );
        /*******************************************/
        /*   create the strings for the variables  */
        /*******************************************/
        str_run = sfs_p->str_ptr;
        sprintf( str_run, "%4.0f / %4.0f", __mou.pos.x, __mou.pos.y );                // actual mouse position 
        str_run += sfs_p->str_size;  
        sprintf( str_run, "%4.0f / %4.0f", __mou.old_pos.x, __mou.old_pos.y );        // old mouse position 
        str_run += sfs_p->str_size;  
        sprintf( str_run, "%4.0f / %4.0f", __mou.travel.x, __mou.travel.y );          // mouse travel delta 
        str_run += sfs_p->str_size;  
        sprintf( str_run, "%d", __mou.but_l );                                        // mouse button left 
        str_run += sfs_p->str_size;  
        sprintf( str_run, "%d", __mou.but_m );                                        // mouse button center 
        str_run += sfs_p->str_size;    
        sprintf( str_run, "%d", __mou.but_r );                                        // mouse buttom right 
        str_run += sfs_p->str_size;    
        sprintf( str_run, "%f", __mou.speed );                                        // mouse speed 

        /******************************************************************/
        /*   create a Vertex_Buffer_Struct with the chars geometry data   */
        /******************************************************************/
        vx = SFS_to_Vx_Buf( sfs_p );                                 


       glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_dbg->vao->vx_b->id );
       G_E_C;                                                   
                                                                            // bind the buffer
       gl_ptr = glMapBufferRange( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, 300, GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT | GL_MAP_UNSYNCHRONIZED_BIT );     // get the pointer
       G_E_C;                                                   



        Destroy_Vertex_Buffer_Struct( vx );

      LeaveCriticalSection( &__cr_sec );
    }
  }
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before any gl-command is executed **the gl-context must be set as current** to the thread that uses those gl-commands.

Just call the `SetCurrent()` command or similar in your thread.

And remember that the main thread (where the app starts) is also a thread. Thus, it also needs `SetCurrent()` if it uses any gl-command.

Comment: Thank you my friend

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [@Ripi2's answe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51269254/2327517) it must be noted that a GL context can be current to at most on thread at any time. One has actually to release the context on the main thread before any worker thread can make it current. As a consequence, using a single OpenGL context in multiple threads is neither convenient nor efficient in most cases.

> I am trying to update the content of a vertex buffer by a thread. Inside the thread function it is not possible to bind the buffer to a target, or retrieve a pointer via `glMapBufferRange`.

There are *much* better options for that, notably:

1. Just keep all GL calls in a single thread, and do the `glMapBufferRange` in the GL thread. While the buffer is mapped, it is writeable by the whole process, so any other thread can fill it.
2. Use multiple GL contexts. Each thread can have it's own context and keep it current all the time. By using *shared* context, the actual data objects like textures, buffers are shared between the context, so you can access the data the GL context in the other thread will be using.

In any case, you will need some proper means of synchronization between those threads, and [OpenGL Sync Objects](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Sync_Object) might be helpful there.